# How to retrieve some output values from SPSS Custom Tables?

Tags: xml, spss

I have been trying to retrieve some specific output values from SPSS Custom Tables and export them to Excel.
The problem is my Ctables syntax generates 2 different tables and I want to retrieve some specific output values from both these tables and then export to Excel.
[Link to screenshot of SPSS custom tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0JmSt.jpg). I have highlighted the values in red that I want to retrieve. I am trying to retrieve these values in XML format, but I am getting an error message. Here is the code.

```
      *1. Retrieve some output values and insert them into text.
 begin program.
import spssaux
gar="CTABLES
    /VLABELS VARIABLES=Institution RES_PAY Status DISPLAY=LABEL
    /TABLE  Status [C] > RES_PAY [C] BY Institution [C][COUNT F40.0, COLPCT.COUNT PCT40.1]
   /CATEGORIES VARIABLES=Institution ORDER=A KEY=VALUE EMPTY=INCLUDE  TOTAL=YES POSITION=AFTER
   /CATEGORIES VARIABLES=RES_PAY EMPTY=INCLUDE
   /CATEGORIES VARIABLES=Status ORDER=A KEY=VALUE EMPTY=INCLUDE
   /SIGTEST TYPE=CHISQUARE ALPHA=0.05 INCLUDEMRSETS=YES  CATEGORIES=ALLVISIBLE."


   cmd = spssaux.CreateXMLOutput(gar, visible=True)
   result=spssaux.GetValuesFromXMLWorkspace(cmd, 'CTABLES', cellAttrib ='text',colCategory='Cat1', rowCategory='Research with pay',rowSubCategory='Yes')
   result1=spssaux.GetValuesFromXMLWorkspace(cmd, 'CTABLES', tableSubtype='CHISQUARE', cellAttrib = 'text',colCategory='Status', rowCategory='Research with pay',rowSubCategory='Sig.')
   OUTPUT NEW
   print result[1]
   print result1[1]

   end program.

  *2. Export output to Excel.

  OUTPUT EXPORT
  /CONTENTS EXPORT= ALL LAYERS=PRINTSETTING MODELVIEWS=PRINTSETTING
 /XLSX DOCUMENTFILE='U:/report1.xlsx' 
 OPERATION=CREATEFILE 
 LOCATION=STARTCELL('C4') NOTESCAPTIONS=YES.
```

This is the error message that I am getting

```
 File "<string>", line 4
    gar="CTABLES
     SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal      ^
```

Can anyone please help me with the code?

Comment: I'm not most familiar with xml approach but it may be what you are trying to do could be done some other way. If you could describe what you trying to achieve, I could try help.

Comment: What languages are options for doing this?

Comment: Thank you for replying, @JigneshSutar. My goal is to retrieve some values from the SPSS custom tables and export it to different tabs within the same excel sheet. This is the snapshot of my SPSS custom tables [link] (http://imgur.com/xKz4KTu), where the values highlighted in red are the ones that I want to retrieve from the tables and export them to excel. Please let me know if you have any further questions.

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error in the Python code.  The line starting gar= is introducing a multi-line literal, so you need to enclose it in triple quotes,

gar="""CTABLES
    /VLABELS VARIABLES=Institution RES_PAY Status DISPLAY=LABEL
    /TABLE  Status [C] > RES_PAY [C] BY Institution [C][COUNT F40.0,   COLPCT.COUNT PCT40.1]
   /CATEGORIES VARIABLES=Institution ORDER=A KEY=VALUE EMPTY=INCLUDE  TOTAL=YES POSITION=AFTER
   /CATEGORIES VARIABLES=RES_PAY EMPTY=INCLUDE
   /CATEGORIES VARIABLES=Status ORDER=A KEY=VALUE EMPTY=INCLUDE
   /SIGTEST TYPE=CHISQUARE ALPHA=0.05 INCLUDEMRSETS=YES    CATEGORIES=ALLVISIBLE."""

However, once you get these values, you are just printing them to the Viewer and exporting everything to the Viewer, which is probably not what you want, since these values were already in a table that will be exported.  This seems to be a very roundabout way of doing all this.  Perhaps if you describe the whole process a simpler solution can be found.

Comment: Thank you. My goal is to retrieve some values from the SPSS custom tables and export it to different tabs within the same excel sheet. This is the snapshot of my SPSS custom tables [link] (http://imgur.com/xKz4KTu), where the values highlighted in red are the ones that I want to retrieve from the tables and export them to excel(in different locations within the same spreadsheet). Please let me know if you have any further questions.